# obtaining a simplified expression for the coefficient of $x^n$

Tags: linear-algebra, combinatorics, generating-functions

> I was trying to find the coefficient of $x^n$ in the expansion of $(1+x)^{-2}(1-2x)^{-2},$ denoted $[x^n]\{(1+x)^{-2}(1-2x)^{-2}\}$. Using the negative binomial theorem, I know that it is equal to
> $$
> \begin{split}
> \sum_{j=0}^n &([x^j](1+x)^{-2})([x^{n-j}](1-2x)^{-2}) \\
>   &= \sum_{j=0}^n {j+1\choose 1}(-1)^j{n-j+1\choose 1}2^{n-j} \\
>   &= \sum_{j=0}^n (j+1)(n-j+1)(-1)^j2^{n-j}.
> \end{split}
> $$

However, I was wondering if there was a way to simplify this expression even further?

Comment: Partial fractions?

Comment: @AnginaSeng where do you see fractions?

Comment: According to Wolfy, 1/((1+x)^2(1-2x)^2) = -8/(27 (2 x - 1)) + 4/(9 (2 x - 1)^2) + 4/(27 (x + 1)) + 1/(9 (x + 1)^2).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As suggested by @AnginaSeng, you can apply partial fraction decomposition:
\begin{align}
\frac{1}{(1+x)^2(1-2x)^2}
&=\frac{1/9}{(1+x)^2}+\frac{4/27}{1+x}+\frac{4/9}{(1-2x)^2}+\frac{8/27}{1-2x}\\
&=\frac{1}{9}\sum_{n \ge 0}\binom{n+1}{1}(-x)^n+\frac{4}{27}\sum_{n\ge 0} (-x)^n+\frac{4}{9}\sum_{n \ge 0} \binom{n+1}{1}(2x)^n+\frac{8}{27}\sum_{n\ge 0} (2x)^n\\
&=\sum_{n \ge 0}\left(\frac{1}{9}\binom{n+1}{1}(-1)^n+\frac{4}{27}(-1)^n+\frac{4}{9}\binom{n+1}{1}2^n+\frac{8}{27} 2^n\right) x^n\\
&=\sum_{n \ge 0}\left(\color{blue}{\frac{(3n+7)(-1)^n+(12n+20)2^n}{27}}\right) x^n
\end{align}

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps here is a way to start. We can define
$$
f(x,y) = \sum_{j=0}^n (j+1)x^j (n-j+1) y^{n-j},
$$
where we ultimately may want to know $f(-1,2)$. Note this is very suggestive of differentiating a much simpler function. In other words, integrating wrt $x$ we get
$$
I_x(x,y) = \sum_{j=0}^n x^{j+1} (n-j+1) y^{n-j} + C(y)
$$
and integrating again wrt $y$
$$
I_{xy}(x,y) = \sum_{j=0}^n x^{j+1} y^{n-j+1} + \int C(y) dy + K(x).
$$
If we let $C(y) = 0 = K(x)$ we have $I_{xy}(x,y)$ which should be easy to compute via straight geometric series. Then take mixed partial wrt $x$ and then $y$ (or the other way around), and evaluate at $x=-1,y=2$.

---

Perhaps a simpler way may be to note that
$$
f(-1,2) = 2^n \sum_{j=0}^n (j+1) (n-j+1) (-2)^{-j}
 = A \sum_{j=0}^n 2^{-j} + B \sum_{j=0}^n j 2^{-j} + C \sum_{j=0}^n j^2 2^{-j},
$$
where you can derive $A,B,C$ by expanding the linear term product and simplifying, and the 3 sums are geometric series $\sum_k a^k$ and 2 its derivatives.